# Create and handle an exception in R

Tags: r, exception

I want to have a function where for a particular exceptions it throws and return a message, and then simply check whether what is returned is one of my defined 'exceptions'. For example say I have the function:

```
divideByX <- function(x){
    # If x is NA throws exception
    if(is.na(x)){
        return(exception('x is NA'))
    }
    # If x is 0 throws exception
    else if(x == 0){
        return(exception('Cannot divide by zero'))
    }
    else{
        return(10/x)
    }
}
```

So if x is 0 it returns the expception 'Cannot divide by zero', if x is NA it returns the exception 'x is NA' and for all other values of x it tries to evaluate the expression 10/x.

Then I would want to run something like this:

```
tempList <- list('a' = 2, 'b' = 0, 'c' = 5, 'd' = NA)
lapply(tempList, function(x){
   if(is.exception(x)){
       return(x)
   }
   else{
       y <- divideByX(x)
       return(y^2)
   }
 })
```

So it first checks if the value is one of my defined exceptions and if so returns the message, else it squares my value, so the above should return

```
$a
[1] 25

$b
[1] 'Cannot divide by zero'

$c
[1] 4

$d
[1] 'x is NA'
```

Does anyone know the best way to do this? Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @joran, division by 0 does not throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function to generate exceptions. The exceptions can be a linear hierarchy that extends the simple error class

```
exception <-
    function(class, msg)
{
    cond <- simpleError(msg)
    class(cond) <- c(class, "MyException", class(cond))
    stop(cond)
}
```

Here's your function

```
divideByX <- function(x){
    # If x is 0 throws exception
    if (length(x) != 1) {
        exception("NonScalar", "x is not length 1")
    } else if (is.na(x)) {
        exception("IsNA", "x is NA")
    } else if (x == 0) {
        exception("DivByZero", "divide by zero")
    }
    10 / x
}
```

and use to generate the output you asked for

```
lapply(tempList, function(x) tryCatch({
    divideByX(x)
}, MyException=function(err) {
    conditionMessage(err)
}))
```

or to treat some exceptions differently from others

```
> lapply(list(NA, 3:5), function(x) tryCatch({
+     divideByX(x)
+ }, IsNA=function(err) {
+     warning(err)  # signal a warning, return NA
+     NA
+ }, NonScalar=function(err) {
+     stop(err)     # fail
+ }))
Error: x is not length 1
In addition: Warning message:
x is NA
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I think this will do the job!

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are always dividing 10, you would want to include the numerator in yoru function.

```
    divideByX <- function(X, num=10) { 

    if(is.na(X)) 
        return('X is NA')
    if(X == 0) 
        return('Cannot divide by zero')

    return(num / X)
    }
```

usage:

```
y <- 3
lapply(tempList, divideByX, num=y^2)
#   $a
#   [1] 4.5
#   
#   $b
#   [1] "Cannot divide by zero"
#   
#   $c
#   [1] 1.8
#   
#   $d 
#   [1] "X is NA"
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, but I was just using that as a simple example, thats not the actual function I wanted to use it on

Comment: @user1165199 No problem. But in that case, I think Joran's original comment might apply. Why not use `try` / `try-catch` ?